# Regex issue using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code:

```
$str = '(Test)';
$final = preg_replace('/\[translate=([a-z]{2})(.*)\]'.preg_quote($matches[3][$i]).'\[\/translate(.*)\]/',$str,$final,-1,$ct);
```

It handles a situation like this okay:

```
test0[translate=en]Hello![/translate]test1
```

Which comes out as:

```
test0(Test)test1
```

But in this situation:

```
[quote:3ggw49so][translate=en]Hello![/translate][/quote:3ggw49so]
```

It comes out as:

```
[quote:3ggw49so](Test)
```

$matches[3][$i] is "Hello!" in this case and $str is "(Test)", and final is the full string that gets overwritten. So it's removing the [/quote:3ggw49so] part, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is a *greedy* quantifier, which means that it matches as much as possible. Your `.*` matches all the way to the last `]`. To make a quantifier non-greedy, append a question mark: `.*?`.

```
$final = preg_replace('/\[translate=([a-z]{2})(.*?)\]'.preg_quote($matches[3][$i]).'\[\/translate(.*?)\]/',$str,$final,-1,$ct);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-greedy switch or `[^\]]*` instead of `.*` which would match "anything until ]".